# Setup sybase DB connection in SQL developer?

Tags: configuration, sybase, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can we connect to the sybase db server using SQL developer.
If yes what are the configuration settings we need to make?

> Can we use the same tnsname.ora file in the Oracle directory or do we need to install a sybase client seperately for getting connection informa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Oracle SQL Developer 3:

You need to download the "JTDS JDBC Driver" extension via Oracle SQL Developer's GUI under Tools / Preferences. The description of this extension only mentions Microsoft SQL Server, but it can also be used for Sybase.

Once it's installed, you should see 2 new tabs in the Create Connection dialog: (MS) "SQLServer" and "Sybase".

I did not have to set up a 3rd party JDBC driver (a reference to a Sybase JDBC connector JAR).

Comment: I couldn't find out how to download "via Oracle SQL Developer's GUI", but I downloaded jTDS driver version 1.2.7 and added the jar to "Third Party JDBC Drivers" under Preferences. Worked fine. I also tried with version 1.3.0, but then I didn't get the connection dialog to open at all. Sticking with 1.2.7

Comment: Works for me with JTDS v1.3.1 on Oracle SQL Developer v3.2.2

Comment: What's the point of this answer without further information on how to use the SQL Developer GUI to download the extension. There is no straightforward way that anyone can simply take for granted as is clearly evident by other answers in this thread. So your answer sounds like - 'Once you do what you don't know how to do, it would simply work.'

Comment: MickJ, I updated the text to clarify which SQL Developer version the solution works for. Unfortunately version 4.0 doesn't seem to have this extension functionality anymore, so a different solution is needed.

Answer (score 4):

You have to configure a new JDBC Driver into SQL Developer.

You can follow these instructions: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/jdbc-migration-1923524.html

Basically you have to download the supported version of the open source jTDS driver (1.2) and then add the jar file in "Third Party JDBC Drivers" on "Preferences".

Comment: Do you think you could distill the instructions down into something that you can write here? If that link ever goes down or gets rid of the instructions in any way, this answer is left dangling.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.
We can download the Sybase plugin which allow us to use SQL Developer for Sybase.
Or we can use JDBC ODBC bridge tweaks for SQL developer.
Can be downloaded for free.

Answer (score 2):

Link to download the [JTDS driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/). Just add it to your Oracle SQL developer and you are done!!