# How do I resolve this error when attempting to use a Sybase connection in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sybase, sqlanywhere

I have downloaded the JTDS driver referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109039/6328288), I then set it up as a 3rd party JDBC Driver in SQL Developer.  I Created a connection to my locally running Sybase server and tested it. The connection tested successfully! Fantastic!

When I try to open the connection to begin working I get the error below, does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.javatools.db.jdbc.JdbcDDLDatabase.registerBuilders(JdbcDDLDatabase.java:443)
at oracle.javatools.db.AbstractDatabase.<init>(AbstractDatabase.java:127)
at oracle.javatools.db.AbstractDatabase.<init>(AbstractDatabase.java:79)
at oracle.javatools.db.ddl.DDLDatabase.<init>(DDLDatabase.java:60)
at oracle.javatools.db.jdbc.JdbcDDLDatabase.<init>(JdbcDDLDatabase.java:61)
at oracle.javatools.db.sybase.AdaptiveServerDatabaseImpl.<init>(AdaptiveServerDatabaseImpl.java:21)
at oracle.javatools.db.sybase.anywhere.AdaptiveServerAnywhereDatabaseImpl.<init>(AdaptiveServerAnywhereDatabaseImpl.java:18)
at oracle.javatools.db.sybase.AdaptiveServerDatabaseFactory.createDatabaseImpl(AdaptiveServerDatabaseFactory.java:33)
at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createDatabaseImpl(DatabaseFactory.java:316)
at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:286)
at oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections.getDatabase(DatabaseConnections.java:656)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections$ConnectionInfo.getDatabase(Connections.java:284)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1180)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1166)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:83)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:38)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.BaseConnectionNode.getConnection(BaseConnectionNode.java:91)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode.getObjectFactory(DatabaseTreeNode.java:90)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:145)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:119)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:199)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:702)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Suppressed: java.sql.SQLException: TDS Protocol error: Invalid packet type 0xc
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2486)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getNextRow(TdsCore.java:805)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.next(JtdsResultSet.java:611)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.close(JtdsResultSet.java:503)
    at oracle.javatools.db.jdbc.JdbcDDLDatabase.registerBuilders(JdbcDDLDatabase.java:467)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ProtocolException: Invalid packet type 0xc
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2475)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is essentially only usable with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set up a connection profile, connect and select from Sybase from SQL Developer with no issues.

Used the jtds-1.3.1.jar driver.

SQL Developer version 17.x

Try that combination to see if it works for you.

Driver Source:
http://jtds.sourceforge.net

Comment: Sorry for the long hang time, I intend to test this but I haven't had time yet